# jquery on mouseup on canvas doesn't work in Chrome but work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, canvas

Using Jquery 3.2.1 when trying to fire a mouseup event in Chrome 58.0.3029.110 on a canvas, it doesn't work. mouseup event work fine if i bind it on something else than a canvas.

Note : the code below works fine on Firefox (on a canvas)..

```
$(document).on('mouseup', '#canvas', function (e) {
   console.log('fired');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well.. looks like chrome ditched "mousedown" and "mouseup" events for "pointerup" and "pointerdown"